# Importação de CSV (que está dentro de um zip) recebido por email automaticamente para a Planilha

Tags: script, google, csv, arquivo-zip, gmail

O que acontece é que diariamente eu recebo um email com um relatório em anexo.
Este anexo está zipado(.zip), e dentro deste zip tem um arquivo CSV.

Preciso que este zip seja convertido para CSV e que este CSV vá automaticamente do meu email (gmail) para a planilha do google, em uma página específica.
Fiz um script, mas estou com dúvida onde estou me perdendo.
Diz que o argumento é invalido na linha 10(var extracted...)

```
function getCSV() {
  var myLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Relatórios X');
  var threads = myLabel.getThreads(0,1);
  var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  var attachments = msgs[0][0].getAttachments();



  var csv =  attachments[0];
  var extracted = Utilities.unzip(csv);
  var string = extracted[0].getDataAsString();
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(string);



  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Relatório_aqui");
sheet.clearContents();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
range.setValues(data);


}
```